# How could I specify a default foreign field value for particular fields in a Foreign Key?

Tags: django, django-models

I would like each instance of a ForeignKey to have a different default value, depending on which property it is in the parent model.

An illustration might make this more clear:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(unique=True)
    manager_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift') # Shift.shift_type should be "M"
    lead_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift') # Shift.shift_type should be "L"
    early_day_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift') # Shift.shift_type should be "ED"
    late_day_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift') # Shift.shift_type should be "LD"
    swing_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift') # Shift.shift_type should be "SW"
    early_evening_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift') # Shift.shift_type should be "EM"
    late_evening_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift') # Shift.shift_type should be "LM"

class Shift(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True}, blank=False)
    shift_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SHIFT_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=False) 

SHIFT_TYPE_CHOICES = { 
    ('M', 'Manager'),
    ('L', 'Lead'),
    ('ED', 'Early Day'),
    ('LD', 'Early Day'),
    ('SW', 'Swing'),
    ('EM', 'Early Evening'),
    ('LM', 'Late Evening'),
}
```

In this case,

So when doing:

```
Day.manager_shift = Shift()
```

Day.manager_shift.shift_type should be "M" automatically

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any built in way of doing that, neither there should be. What would happen if you did:

```
>>> my_shift = Shift()
>>> Day.manager_shift = my_shift
>>> Day.lead_shift = my_shift
>>> my_shift.shift_type
???
```

A better option would be overriding the `save` method of `Day` to check every field of the saved object and: a) if there's no `shift_type`, add the correct one; b) if there is a shift time, but a wrong one, raise an error (not the cleanest solution, but I don't know of anything better).

**Update:** I just [read](http://djangodays.com/2009/05/11/django-foreign-key-default-value-example/) (*Edit:* and Rohan also pointed out) that you **can** give a default value to a `ForeignKey`, but you should do so in the form of a function:

```
def default_type(type):
    temp = [type] # Necessary because Python can't handle closures properly sometimes
    def closure():
        return Shift.objects.get(shift_type=temp[0])
    return closure

class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(unique=True)
    manager_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift', default=default_type('M'))
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but in the same way you can specify default values for fields of a model whose values haven't been specified, it seems it would make sense to me that you could specify a default foreign field value for fields which you are creating new instances of.

Comment: Yes, but what would you use as the value? The only thing that makes sense to me would be using the primary key of the other model (since that's the only thing that can uniquely identify a row in that model).

Answer (score 1):

You can have default value as callable, so you can do this:

```
def get_m_shift():
    return Shift.objects.get(shitf_type='M')

    class Day(models.Model):
        date = models.DateField(unique=True)
        manager_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift', default=get_m_shift)
```

I think you have to write function to get each shift type. I'm not sure the default callable takes parameter.

Comment: While you can't pass a parameter to it, you can have another function return the callable (i.e. create a closure). See my answer for an example.

Comment: Yea this isn't quite what I want either. The Shift objects doesn't exist yet. I want new Shift objects created to have that "M" value if they are assigned to the manager_shift property. The code I'd expect to see is something like: manager_shift = models.ForeignKey('Shift', shift.shift_type="M")

Comment: @Ben174 If you want to create it, you need to get _User_ instance to create _Shift_, is that available?

Comment: @Rohan absolutely. I wouldn't create a Shift without knowing the User and the shift_type.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a separate 'Day' model?

```
SHIFT_TYPE_CHOICES = { 
    ('M', 'Manager'),
    ('L', 'Lead'),
    ('ED', 'Early Day'),
    ('LD', 'Early Day'),
    ('SW', 'Swing'),
    ('EM', 'Early Evening'),
    ('LM', 'Late Evening'),
}

class Shift(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User',
                             limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True},
                             blank=False)
    shift_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                  choices=SHIFT_TYPE_CHOICES,
                                  blank=False) 
    shift_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('shift_date','shift_user','shift_type'),)
```

This will prevent duplicate shifts for the same user on the same date, and only one combination of shift type and user.  You can adjust it based on what you require. So if you need multiple shifts on the same date, remove `shift_date`. The [documentation for `unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) explains how this works.

Now, to find out who was the manager on a particular day:

```
for s in Shift.objects.filter(shift_type='M',
                              shift_date=datetime.datetime.today()):
    print s.user
```

Or to print the days entire roster:

```
for s in Shift.objects.filter(shift_date=datetime.datetime.today()):
    print "%s: %s\n" % (s.get_shift_type_display(),s.user)
```

Comment: I agree that a Day object doesn't make sense completely. But this object model is already being used heavily in the views. It would take some major refactoring to remove it. I inherited this project.